# How to enable @Required?

Tags: java, spring, spring-3

How to enable the @Required annotation in Java (Spring 3.1) ? Not in a xml, but in through Java. Also under which annotation I put this enabling? Under @Feature (in @FutureConfiguration or @Bean (in @Configuration) ?

**Edit:**

```
    @Feature
    public MvcAnnotationDriven annotationDriven(ConversionService conversionService) {
        return new MvcAnnotationDriven().conversionService(conversionService)
                .argumentResolvers(new CustomArgumentResolver());
    }
```

Does this enables all annotations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@anubhava's answer works, but he's referenced the Spring 2.0 manual, which is 5 years old.

In XML config, Spring 3.x has a more elegant approach: `<context:annotation-config/>`. This also enabled a whole other bunch of features that you'll probably want, whereas `RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` only enables a few.

See [Spring 3.x manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-context).

If you're using `@Bean`-style config, then annotations like `@Required` should *already* be enabled, since that's how `@Bean` works. However, it's possible that this is a bug - Spring 3.1 is still in early beta, and big chunks of it are likely to be broken.

Unless you really know what you're doing, I strongly recommend sticking to 3.0.x.

Comment: other annotations like @Autowired work, but I did set the @Required annotation in one of the bean classes however didn't set the property and it didn't throw the exception when launching. But it did throw it when changing the @Required to @Autowired.

Comment: Check the main post, added code i've in @FeatureConfiguration. Does it enables the @Required, at least should?

Comment: @Richard: I'm not sure, I haven't played with 3.1 yet.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Spring manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/metadata.html):

> There is one last little (small, tiny)
>   piece of Spring configuration that is
>   required to actually 'switch on' this
>   behavior. Simply annotating the
>   'setter' properties of your classes is
>   not enough to get this behavior. You
>   need to enable a component that is
>   aware of the @Required  annotation and
>   that can process it appropriately.
>
> This component is the
>   RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor
>   class. This is a special
>   BeanPostProcessor implementation that
>   is @Required-aware and actually
>   provides the 'blow up if this required
>   property has not been set' logic. It
>   is very easy to configure; simply drop
>   the following bean definition into
>   your Spring XML configuration.

```
<bean class=
"org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
```

Please check: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/metadata.html

Comment: This is ancient. Why do people upvote this? The OP specifically said version 3.1, but this is 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Use [`AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/context/annotation/AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.html) if you don't want to use XML:

> Standalone application context,
>   accepting annotated classes as input -
>   in particular `@Configuration`-annotated
>   classes, but also plain `@Components`
>   and JSR-330 compliant classes using
>   javax.inject annotations. Allows for
>   registering classes one by one
>   (`register(java.lang.Class...)`) as well
>   as for classpath scanning
>   (`scan(java.lang.String...)`).
>
> In case of multiple Configuration
>   classes, Bean methods defined in later
>   classes will override those defined in
>   earlier classes. This can be leveraged
>   to deliberately override certain bean
>   definitions via an extra Configuration
>   class.

**Sample Code:**

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext =
new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(
    "com.mycompany.package1",
    "com.mycompany.package2",
    "com.mycompany.package3"
    // etc.
);
applicationContext.refresh();
```

Comment: I run the Spring with Jetty. Where do I add such simple code? Currently I've a Launcher class which the reads web.xml which points to the MvcFeatures and MvcBeans.

Comment: @Richards Oh, in a web context you should use [`AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/web/context/support/AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.html) instead.